# How do I mock leaflet for jest tests?

Tags: react-leaflet

I use a custom icon in L.Icon in a CRA project. It keeps saying L is undefined when running jest tests. How would I mock leaflet to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer on a similar issue in `leaflet` itself

```
What I can recommend for testing is the following,
 just mock leaflet using this in your test file,
 that is rendering the map component:
jest.mock('leaflet')

And then you place this leaflet mock you can
find in react-leaflet into the jest mocks folder
 (__mocks__/leaflet.js, download the current file from: 
https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/__mocks__/leaflet.js)

That should be enough in most cases.
```

ref: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/6297#issuecomment-499809735